# stx-btree store on disc

Tags: c++, database, b-tree

I'm developing small database, and I have deiced to use stx-btree implementation for store the data in btree.

Is it possible to store [stx-btree](http://idlebox.net/2007/stx-btree/) on disc?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I need hold in memory piece of btree and load/save required tree node when it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know very little about c or c++ or even btree's but saw this question while reviewing and googled it as it looked interesting ! ...

Have a look at this gitHub page :

https://github.com/fakechris/stx-btree-ondisk

```
--- Extensions ---

Beyond the usual STL interface the B+ tree classes support some extra goodies.

// Output the tree in a pseudo-hierarchical text dump to std::cout. This
// function requires that BTREE_DEBUG is defined prior to including the btree
// headers. Furthermore the key and data types must be std::ostream printable.
void print() const;

// Run extensive checks of the tree invariants. If a corruption in found the
// program will abort via assert(). See below on enabling auto-verification.
void verify() const;

// Serialize and restore the B+ tree nodes and data into/from a binary image.
// This requires that the key and data types are integral and contain no
// outside pointers or references.
void dump(std::ostream &os) const;
bool restore(std::istream &is);
```

Comment: What happens if the btree is too large? I think that will be not enough memory. I need hold in memory piece of btree and load required tree node when it's necessary.

Comment: @Zheka as I said - i have no idea about c++ so im afraid I cant help you with that one ... sorry !!!